# How to run a program on each file in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

So I have a python file `file.py`. And I have a directory that has many `.txt` file. So I was wondering how do I do `python3 file.py txt1.txt`, `python3 file.py txt2.txt` and so on for every txt file in the directory?

Comment: are you trying to read every file with `.txt` extension?

Comment: @midrizi yes! that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Here is the alternative solution using find:

```
find /path/to/your/txtfiles/*.txt -type f -exec python3 file.py {} \;
```

I like find because I think it makes it easier to recursively search through directories while matching specific conditions.

Here `-type f` is selecting only regular files, and `-exec` is running your script with the filename being substituted in place of the curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

Just pipe the output of *ls* (filtering the files you want) into stdin of *xargs*:

```
❯❯❯ ls *.txt | xargs -I{} python3 file.py {}
```

Comment: No, [don't use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The shell already expands `*.txt` before `ls` even runs. There is no need for `xargs` then either.